# Laravel 5 handle nested files request

Tags: php, laravel

My html with name:

```
<input type="file" value="" name="postmeta[featured_image]">
```

my `dd($request->files->all())`

[image]

So, my actions should start after:

```
if ($request->hasFile('postmeta')) {
   // How do I can handle files request with nested files values here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

First of all in form open tag dnt forget enable multipart/form-data by:

```
{!! Form::open(['action'=>'PostsController@update', 'files' => true]) !!}
```

and at finaly:

```
if ($request->hasFile('postmeta')) {
            $files = $request->file('postmeta');
            foreach ( $files as $file_key => $file ) {

                if($file->isValid()) {
                    $filedata = [
                        'ext'   => $file->getClientOriginalExtension(),
                        'mime'  => $file->getClientMimeType(),
                        'name'  => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                        'size'  => $file->getClientSize(),
                        'error' => $file->getError(),
                        'valid' => $file->isValid()
                    ];
                    $file->move(public_path().'/uploads', "uploaded_".$filedata['name']);
                }
            }
        }
```